# How can I stop a DataBricks notebook referencing old versions of my egg files?

Tags: databricks, egg

On DataBricks on Azure:

I follow these steps:

- create a library from a python egg, say simon_1_001.egg which contains a module simon.
- attach the library to a cluster and restart the cluster
- attach a notebook to the cluster and run:

  import simon as s
  print s.`__file__`
- run the notebook and it correctly gives me a file name including the
  string 'simon_1_001.egg'
- then detach and delete the egg file, even emptying trash.
- restart the cluster, detach and attach the notebook run it and
  instead of complaining that it can't find module simon, it runs and
  displays the same string

Similarly if I upload a newer version of the egg, say simon_1_002.egg, it still displays the same string.
If I wait half an hour clear and rerun a few times then eventually it will pick up the new library and will display simon_1_002.egg.

How can I properly clear down the old egg files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simon, this is a bug in Databricks platform. When a library is created in Databricks using jar, the file is stored in `dbfs:/FileStore` and `/databricks/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` for Py2 and `/databricks/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` for Py3 clusters.

In both the `jar` and `egg` cases, the path is stored when a library is created. When a library is detached and removed from Trash, it is supposed to removed the copy from DBFS which it does not do currently.

To alliviate this inconsistency issue, you might want to check the environment subtab in Spark UI or using `%sh ls` in a cell for looking in appropriate paths to make sure if a library is removed correctly or not and also remove them using `%sh rm` command before restarting the cluster and attaching a newer version of the library.

Answer (score 2):

There's another fun Databricks platform bug in job dependencies. Removing a dependent library in UI doesn't do anything, so old dependency versions are stuck there and jobs fail even if you delete the jar/egg from dbfs.

The only option seems to be updating the jobs using [CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html#jobs-cli) or [API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/jobs.html#create). So you'll need to do something along these lines (CLI):

```
databricks jobs list
```

Find your job id, then:

```
databricks jobs get --job-id 5
```

Save the output to a json file `job.json`, remove stuff outside `settings`, copy stuff from `settings` to the root of the json document, remove the unwanted libraries, and then do:

```
 databricks jobs reset --job-id 5 --json-file job.json
```